# exec nodejs script from php

Tags: php, node.js

i have problem with a nodejs script used from php using exec() in a loop .
the problem is that the script is executed only once then just errors.
here is the php code :

```
for ($i=0; $i <= ((mysqli_num_rows($repp)/50)-1); $i++) 
{   

  $req = "select * from items  limit ".$id.",50"; 
  $rep = mysqli_query($link,$req);
  $names = "";
  $id = $id + 50;

  while($donne = mysqli_fetch_array($rep))
    {
            $names = $names.$donne["item_name"].',';
    }
  $resultat = '"'.rtrim($names, ",").'"';
  exec("node node_opskins.js ".$resultat,$out);
  $result =implode($out);
  $a = str_replace("'", '"', $result);
  $a = preg_replace('/([\w\d]+): /', '"$1": ', $a);
  foreach ( json_decode($a,true) as $key => $value) 
  {
    echo $key . " : " . $value['market_price'] . "<br/>";
    $req = "update items set opskins_suggested = '".($value['market_price']/100)."' where item_name = '".addslashes($key)."'";
        mysqli_query($link,$req);
 }
 sleep(10);
}
```

and here is the Nodejs script :

```
var OPSkinsAPI = require('@opskins/api');
var opskins = new OPSkinsAPI(my opskins api key);
var item = process.argv[2].split(",");
opskins.getSuggestedPrices(730, item, function(err,price){ 


    console.log(price);

});
```

Comment: Please provide your error messages too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is a very inefficient way to achieve your goal. It would be much mor efficient if your Node app was listening on some port and provided answers to the requests (HTTP or some local IPC) from your PHP app. That having been said, if you still want to run your Node app as you do now, you should handle errors in Node:

```
var OPSkinsAPI = require('@opskins/api');
var opskins = new OPSkinsAPI(my opskins api key);
var item = process.argv[2].split(",");
opskins.getSuggestedPrices(730, item, function(err,price){
    // handle errors:
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error:', err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log(price);
});
```

That way you will be able to know what happened. Otherwise your program would just return string `"undefined"` on the stdout and your PHP program wouldn't know that something went wrong.

You also need to handle the errors in PHP.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out where will this `console.error` show?